# Can I disable Notify Activity Assignees for some Activities and/or user levels and leave it on for other Activities/user levels?

Tags: extension, email, activities, hooks

We're on Civi 4.6.21 and Drupal 7.

Under Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Settings there is a setting - "Notify Activity Assignees - When enabled, contacts who are assigned activities will automatically receive an email notification with a copy of the activity."  - with a checkbox to enable the setting.

I want to be able to send e-mail notifications based on Activity type, or Activity Subject, or Campaign to which that Activity is linked, or Assigned To contact user level - so, for example, staff who are Assigned an Activity called Membership Signup (of a 'target' contact, the With contact) always receive an e-mail notification; but, volunteers who are Assigned an Activity of Card Signup, with Subject of Protect Puppies as part of a Campaign called Protect Puppies 2016, do not receive an e-mail notification of that Assigned Activity.

Sending e-mail notifications of Assigned Activities is really handy - but not desired in all use cases.

So - how can I disable Notify Activity Assignees for some Activities and/or user levels and leave it on for other Activities/user levels?

Thanks!

Comment: I removed civirules since this does not appear to be specific to that, and comes up in searching for Tag = civirules

Answer (score 3):

The extension mentioned by Peter in the answer is now moved into core and can be used from 4.7.30 version. See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21380

It introduces a new setting which blocks some activity types to send an email to the assignees.

To enable this, navigate to `Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences` and select `Notify Activity Assignees` checkbox. It will then display a multi-select box to choose some activity type which you don't wish to send notifications for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not available out of the box. It'd involve writing a new feature / extension.

It looks like the magic happens in the [CRM_Activity_BAO_Activity::sendToAssignee](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php#L2770) method. This method takes an activity object and an array of contacts to send the mail to.

So would involve a bit of coding, I'm afraid, but is a job that could / should be done "the right way [tm]". Which I will be so bold as to suggest is:

1. implement a hook to do the filtering, and rewrite some of the code that calls sendToAssignee so that it is aware of the hook
2. write an extension that with a UI that implements the hook so that configuration is easier and people don't have to write code each time they want to implement the hook.

Comment: michaelmcandrew thanks so much for pointing me to the right place in the  core code. I'm wondering if I can do what I want using CiviRules instead - leave Notify Activity Assignees of in Settings and create a CiviRule for each particular use case to notify activity assignees via e-mail. Hmmm....

Comment: @JoeMcLaughlin maybe! :) let us know how you get on

Comment: Joe - any progress with that approach?

Comment: petednz - have not had a chance to try this using CiviRules - it was causing problems with cron so had to disable it, again.

Answer (score 1):

Just come across this old question.  I wrote a hook for this a while back that needs some attention. (Part 1 of Michael's answer)

If you can help review [CRM-20638](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20638) and [PR-10417](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10417) we can move this forward.

Comment: Aidan thanks so much and I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

We have an extension for this now. It is going through some testing process, but since I stumbled on this I thought I should update here. Will add more when it gets published

Comment: Thanks Peter! Looking forward to checking out the extension.

Comment: see jitendra's answer joe